# A2208 missing operator error

Tags: assembly, masm

It is giving error A2208 missing operator error in line number 5 (`buffer db 10 dwb['$']`).

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
    num dw 4567
    buffer db 10 dwb['$']

.code 
    main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds , ax
    mov ax , num
    mov bx, offset buffer
    .
    .

 l1 :

end main
```

Comment: In what assembler, MASM, TASM, FASM? other?

Comment: What did you even want to achieve with `buffer db 10 dwb['$']` ?

Comment: `buffer db 10 dup ('$')` to fill the buffer with 10 $ chars.

Comment: Assembler's aren't very forgiving of users making up their own syntax for things. ;)

Comment: MASM @netvipeC assembler i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my own question

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
    num dw 4567
    buffer db 10 dup('$') ; only change here

.code 
    main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds , ax
    mov ax , num
    mov bx, offset buffer

 l1 :
    mov dx, 0
    mov cx ,10 
    div cx
    add dl,48
    mov [bx] , dl
    inc bx
    cmp ax, 0
    jne l1

    mov dx , offset buffer
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

    main endp
    end main
```